# Reviewboard tests.py how to run it

Tags: python, django, review-board

I have a fresh install of Reviewboard 1.6.3 which is running through python and django. The folder structure is basically as follows:

/reviewboard

-manage .py

-settings .py

-settings_local .py

-/diffviewer

--tests .py

In that case how would I run tests .py because it seems that it is looking for so-called DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. I'm not sure how to really use that environment variable. Can you help me how will this work

Answer (score 1):

Run with:

```
python manage.py test
```

Answer (score 0):

You run it like you do any Django project:

```
 ./manage.py test
```

However unless you're doing your own development on that project, you shouldn't need to run the tests.